# Is it recommended to store constant String in "extension String"

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm implementing an `Alamofire Router`. And I want to manage my constant url for each api. Normally I create a `struct` to store them like the following code:

```
private struct API {
    static let foo = "domain/models/foo"
    static let bar = "doamin/models/bar"
}
```

But recently I found it also could be implemented in `String` extension, like

```
private extension String {
    static let foo = "domain/models/foo"
    static let bar = "doamin/models/bar"
}
```

In this way, it's easier to me to use it. like

```
// from
let urlFromStruct: String = API.foo

// to
let urlFromExtension: String = .foo
```

Because extending `String` means the constants become String's static properties. If I don't omit the `String`, the code would become

```
let urlFromExtension: String = String.foo
```

and to prevent these constant will be accessed in other files. I declare the extension with private.

**So I wonder is it recommended to implement it by the `extension` way? or any other suggestion is appreciated.**

Comment: I would recommend to always scope constants depending on their meaning, not depending on their type. Grouping constants depending on type just ends up in having tens of different constants in one file. Don't write code that is short, write code that is easily readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is really not recommended. Even though the type of the values you are storing is string, those values have no logical connection to the `String` class, so adding them as a type property is a bad idea in my opinion.

Those API endpoints are only connected to your business logic, so they should be stored in a type only related to your business logic and not in a "generic" type even if you declare them `private`.

It might also be a good idea to store the endpoints in an `enum` rather than in a `struct` or `class`.

```
private enum API {
    static let foo = URL(string: "domain/models/foo")!
    static let bar = URL(string: "domain/models/bar")!
}
```

Comment: tbh, it's probably best to store these as `URL` static members of a caseless enum.

Comment: That's a good idea, thanks for the input, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Why `enum` instead of `struct`?

Comment: @casvaart have a look at [Caseless enums](https://codecram.asoftwareco.com/2017/12/14/caseless-enums/), it gives quite a good summary on the topic. TLDL: with a `struct` you need to declare the `init private`, otherwise the `struct` can be instantiated (but even then you can instantiate it from inside the type itself), which you don't want for just storing static properties on it, so using an `enum` with static properties is the only way that such type can never be instantiated by accident.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather recommend you use an enum for that like:

```
enum API: String { {
    case foo = "domain/models/foo"
    case bar = "doamin/models/bar"
}

let urlFromEnum: String = API.foo.rawValue
```

Extending a String with static strings is not recommended, because those are business properties and not a String properties.

Answer (score 1):

Semantically it is a little awkward to add constants as a fileprivate extension to `String`, but on the other hand being able to use them throughout the file with only the dot notation feels natural less verbose than `API.myPath` for example.

This is one area where Swift doesn't seem to have a strong opinon (yet).